# Adding new participant to a breakout room after breakouts are in progress

Tags: conferencing, zoom-meeting

Suppose I am hosting a Zoom meeting and I have already created some breakout rooms and moved people into breakouts.  Then a new participant joins the call.  I'd like to find out someone new arrived and add them to an existing breakout room.  If I am in a breakout room at the time, how can I find out that someone new has arrived and should be assigned to a breakout room?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to exit from the room, check for new people, and add them to the appropriate room. You must do this from your host screen and controls.  If you have two screens or computers you might be able to do it from a second computer. In our meetings the host is normally not in a breakout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I want to make sure I am understanding your answer.  I believe you to be saying: (1) while I'm in a breakout room, there's no way to be notified that someone has joined the main room; (2) while I'm in a breakout room, there's no way to assign a new participant to some breakout room.  Do I have that correct?  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Correct . If you are in a participant room, you cannot add an incoming participant to a room.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered through experimentation that you can detect when someone new enters the room because there will be an indicator above the "breakouts" icon on the toolbar: if 2 people have entered but not yet been placed into a breakout room, there will be a red (2) hovering over the "breakouts" icon.  When opening the breakouts window, they will show up under "Unassigned".

The host can then assign them to a breakout room.  There is no need to switch back to the main room to make the assignment: the host can assign them to a breakout room from whereever the host is, even if the host is in a separate breakout room.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issue may be around whether you are using a Waiting Room or not. If you're using a Waiting Room, you should get a notification as the Host if you're in a Breakout Room that someone is now unassigned but you don't know if they're in the Waiting Room or the Meeting Room. If you assign them to, say, Breakout Room 2 and they're in the Waiting Room, they are still stuck in the Waiting Room, but now you don't know they're stuck there! Worse still, if you realise, leave your Breakout Room, let them in from the Meeting Room, you can't now assign them to Breakout Room 2 because Zoom thinks they've already been assigned there. It's a bit bizarre. If you do that, you need to assign them to the wrong Breakout Room, then assign them to the right one! Worse still, since the latest update (5.4.2), I'm not even getting a notification that someone is unassigned when I'm in the Breakout Room. I only get the notification when I'm in the Meeting Room.